# How do I resolve images in a HTML file loaded by WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 and I am able to load a web page using

```
string exePath = Application.ExecutablePath ;
int n =  exePath.LastIndexOf("\\");
// the web page & image is in the same directory as the executable
string filename = exePath.Substring(0, n)+ "\\switchboard.htm"; 
webBrowser1.DocumentStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
```

The text of the web page loads ok, but this

```
&lt;img src="cardpack1.jpg" height="200" alt="card"&gt;
```

results in a broken image.

The image file is in the same directory as the html file.
I'm not even sure what to google.  All of the questions I've found appear to be doing
fancier things like resolving images from resource bundles and trying to dynamically
display/not display images.

So, any advice would be appreciated (even if it's just ... google for x, y, z)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the [WebBrowser.Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161352.aspx) Method instead. A URI can be a local file. Its also a good idea to use the Path methods to create your string.

```
     string exePath = Application.ExecutablePath;
     string htmPath = Path.Combine( Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath) , "switchboard.htm");

     webBrowser1.Navigate(htmPath);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer this question.  Your solution was almost correct and definitely helped me get past being stumped.  The change I needed to make was to add the protocol to the htmPath.

string exePath = Application.ExecutablePath ;
string url = "file://" + Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath), "switchboard.htm");
webBrowser1.Navigate(url);

And using Path.Combine and Path.GetDirectoryName are much nicer than what I was doing.